# What is the most professional way to size webpage background?

Tags: html, css, resize

Hi I have seen many different sites using different techniques on background scaling and I was wondering which is more professional. I am building a website and I would like to make sure it is professional. I have seen some background images that are scaling and resizing to the size of the browser, and I have also seen backgrounds that have a fixed image based on your resolution that does not resize when the browser is resized.

So my question is which of these is more professional in the business world?

If there are other methods that are more professional I think many of us new programmers would like this information to start on the proper path to professionalism.

Thank you for reading and taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: Most proper way, or is just due to preference?

Comment: This question is totally subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"and I was wondering which is more professional" - Actually this depends on your requirements of the application you are developing.Your perception of "professionalism" on a social networking site may be different from an ERP solution.

What I suggest you is first understand the requirement right.If you are new to ajax and JavaScript , be knowledgeable of them because most of the re-sizing stuff works with them.And then study the themes used in reputed places.

Sometimes this may be useful to you http://www.developphp.com/list_php_video.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "background-size: cover" it's a new css3 prop but it's unsupported on some mobile devices. So you must integrate it with some javascript fallback. With that setting the aspect ration is conserved and also the image always fill the container. Some fix is this..

```
.myclass {
  background-image: url('blabla.png');
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='blabla.png',sizingMethod='scale');

}
```

...but this is not the most professional way